# Access webpack entry points in compiled code

Tags: webpack

If I have multiple entry points defined like this

```
entry: {
  home: "./home.js",
  about: "./about.js",
  contact: "./contact.js"
}
```

can I access the names of the entry points in my compiled code e.g. in `home.js` for generating a navigation? Or is it better in this case to generate the entry points with a function that shares the configuration with the code that will be compiled?